# Align image with Sinusoidal projection correctly using imshow and cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot an image with a Sinusoidal projection using imshow but if I use the `transform=ccrs.Sinusoidal(central_longitude=128)` it's not working at all and using the transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() the coastlines and image are not aligned. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
img_extent = (122.8109, 133.2922, 32.8286, 43.1708)
img = plt.imread('Korea.A2004004.0445.250m.jpg')
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Image is from: https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/69000/69679/Korea.A2004004.0445.250m.jpg

Comment: What is the `metadata` of the image? Do you use it in your code?

Comment: Yes, the image extent is 122.8109, 133.2922, 32.8286, 43.1708, and the central longitude of the image is 128.

Comment: Where did you get the image and extent from? The coordinates of the extent you use clearly don't match a Sinusoidal projection.